# How to expunge an object twice

Tags: sqlalchemy

Does anybody know how to correctly expunge an object from two different sessions.

In the snippet below, the last access to `model.id` fails with a `DetachedInstanceError`.

```
with session_scope() as session:
    model = session.query(Model).filter(Model.id='some_id').first()
    print(model.id)
    # Change Model
    session.commit()
    session.expunge(model)
print(model.id)
with session_scope() as session:
    session.add(model)
    # Change Model
    session.commit()
    session.expunge(model)
print(model.id)
```

Where `session_scope` is defined as shown in https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html

Comment: `session.add(model)` is wrong, you should `merge()` (and remember that it returns another object, not the one you pass it). `add()` is used to add new objects to a session.

Comment: Ilja, that does not seem to have any impact. What did work was to set `expire_on_commit=False`.

Comment: Did not say it'd solve your entire issue, but it still stands that `Session.add()` is for adding new (transient) objects and `merge()` for merging objects between sessions.